# Can you buy Uzbekistan Airways tickets online?

Tags: online-resources, airlines, tickets

Uzbekistan Airways [has a website](http://www.uzairways.com/), and yes, I can click through to the English version.  But after navigating around, they have a timetable, but if you want to book a flight, you have to ... wait for it ... CALL THEM.

Timezones and costs notwithstanding, is there another website online where you can purchase tickets for Uzbekistan Airways flights between Bangkok and Tashkent?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I tried KAYAK and I found flights operated by Uzbekistan Airways there!!

[image: Uzbekistan Airways]

While you can't buy on Kayak, if you follow the ticket, it'll take you to the online travel agency [Vayama](http://www.vayama.com/) and you can certainly purchase them there.

Comment: Odd. I just tried again and still it doesn't show on kayak for me.  Maybe it's the dates...will try yours now.

Comment: Aha, when I had [2 adults in the search string](https://www.kayak.com/#/flights/TAS,nearby-BKK,nearby/2012-09-17-flexible/2adults) it wasn't showing it, but [with just one](https://www.kayak.com/#/flights/TAS,nearby-BKK,nearby/2012-09-17-flexible/) it does.  They surely can't have just one ticket available....

Comment: Technically you can't actually buy tickets on kayak anyway, but in this case it sends you to vayama.  If you add in to your answer that it will show you the tickets and then you can buy them through vayama, I'll accept the answer.  Actually stuff it, I'll add it in myself and accept your answer.